# Dashboard chart components appearing in black and white for end users

Tags: charts, report-chart

I can't find a single thing online about this issue.   Very simply, as an admin I'm creating chart components on a public dashboard and sharing this with other non admin users.

The dashboards appear and work fine but most of the charts that for me are in colours such as blue are all in black for the other users.

Comment: Can you check if those users maybe have the [Color-Blind Palette on Charts](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004705) checked on their user record?

Comment: brilliant thank you @RobinDeBondt !  Do you want to add an answer to get some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users with the [Color-Blind Palette on Charts](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004705) setting checked on their record will see the charts you have defined with an alternative color palette.